# AEM asset dam path change update automatically

Tags: reference, path, aem, dam

Say, we give an image path from dam in a page. Later we move the image to a different path.

Is there a way to automatically update the original page where the path was given, to the new path?

Essentially, the page must be linked to the asset and not the resource path, so wherever the image might be, that path should get updated.

Is this something configurable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/author/assets/managing-assets-touch-ui.html#Moving%20or%20Renaming%20Assets), during moving asset using DAM you should see additional step allowing you to choose which of its references should be updated:

> If the assets being moved have any referencing pages, assets, or collections an additional Adjust References tab appears after the Select Destination tab.

AEM has an internal mechanism which tracks paths to assets in JCR content properties.